# Переменные в регулярных выражениях

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Господа, шаблон рег. выражения состоит из трех частей - переменная, рег. выражение, переменная, например `stringBefore + @"([\w]+)" + stringAfter`.
Всё бы хорошо, но в `stringAfter` помимо букв есть открывающая скобка и *Regex* думает, что это часть регулярного выражения, и поэтому выкидывается ошибка "*Нет парных закрывающих скобок*".

Как сделать чтобы переменные распознавались как обычный текст?

Comment: [экранируйте свои скобки `\(` в переменных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: это конечно логично, но мыло ли какие ещё могут попасться спецсимволы, да и перебирать все сецсимволы и экранировать дополнительные траты. Или другого способа нет?

Comment: я выше уже привел ссылку на методы `Regex.escape`, он сделает все что вам надо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте [`Regex.Escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Преобразует минимальный набор символов (`\`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `^`, `$`, `.`, `#` и пробел), заменяя их соответствующими escape-кодами. При этом обработчику регулярных выражений дается команда интерпретировать эти символы буквально, а не как метасимволы.

Пример объявления:

```
var reg = new Regex($@"{Regex.Escape(stringBefore)}(\w+){Regex.Escape(stringAfter)}");
```

В старших версиях C# можно использовать аналогичный

```
var reg = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}(\w+){1}", Regex.Escape(stringBefore), Regex.Escape(stringAfter)));
```

Comment: Эх, ведь все же уже придумано, а мы пытаемся заново изобретать велосипед..)

Answer (score 1):

В таком случае я вижу только 1 способ: пройтись посимвольно по `stringBefore` и `stringAfter` и все символы, которые используются в регулярном выражении как `зарезервированные`, экранировать.

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант, если параметр в фигурных скобках `{n}`:

```cs
Regex rg = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]{0}{1}{2})\b",
    Regex.Unescape("{"), Regex.Escape(n.ToString()), Regex.Unescape("}")));
```

Или воспользоваться `Replace`:

```cs
string pattern = Regex.Replace(@"\b([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]{n})\b", "n", n.ToString());
```